# delete rows in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `log` table as follows:

```
id  status1 status2  ref  dateofchange
1     10      12      33     1.1.10
2     10      12      34     1.1.15
3     5        8      14     1.5.10
4     10      12      33     2.1.10
```

and another table `tab` as follows:

```
id ref qty  commitdate
1   17  5    1.1.10
2   33  8    1.1.10
3   34  7    1.12.14
4   34  8    1.2.16
5   34  8    1.1.15
```

I have a query which gives me rows from `log` table:

```
select *
from log
where status1=10 and status2=12
```

this gives:

```
id  status1 status2  ref  dateofchange
1     10      12      33     1.1.10
2     10      12      34     1.1.15
4     10      12      33     2.1.10
```

For each of these rows I want to delete all rows from tab where `log.ref=tab.ref and tab.commitdate<=log.dateofchange`

after deletion tab table should look like:

```
id ref qty  commitdate
1   17  5    1.1.10
4   34  8    1.2.16
```

i tried to do it with WITH query:

```
With l as (
    select *
    from log
    where status1=10 and status2=12
)
delete from tab where l.ref=tab.ref and tab.commitdate<=l.dateofchange
```

However this does not work.

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "l"

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining a table in a `DELETE` statement has a different syntax as in the `update` or `select` statement. You need to use `USING` in order to join a table in a `delete` statement

```
with l as (
    select *
    from log
    where status1=10 and status2=12
)
delete from tab 
using l
where l.ref=tab.ref 
  and tab.commitdate <= l.dateofchange;
```

or without the CTE:

```
delete from tab 
using log l
where l.ref = tab.ref 
  and l.status1 = 10
  and l.status2 = 12
  and tab.commitdate <= l.dateofchange;
```

This can also be written without a join, using a co-related sub-query:

```
delete from tab
where exists (select *
              from log as l
              where l.status1 = 10 
                and l.status2 = 12
                and tab.commitdate <= l.dateofchange);
```

Comment: I don't understand the co-related sub-query. I don't want to delete everything from tab... I want to delete only rows where the ref is the same and the date is earlier than what is written in log table.

Comment: @java: that's what the `exists` operator in the `where` clause is for. The statement does not delete all rows in `tab` - only those, where a row in the sub-query exists (hence the name).

Comment: But how dows it check the dates? dates aren't neccecrly a match.

Comment: @java: the check is *in* the sub-query: `and tab.commitdate <= l.dateofchange`

Answer (score 1):

In order to `JOIN` you need a `USING` clause:

```
WITH l AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM log
    WHERE status1=10 AND status2=12
)
DELETE FROM tab 
USING l
WHERE l.ref=tab.ref AND tab.commitdate <= l.dateofchange;
```